# How to remove the Cancel button from a save as dialog in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, button, dialog

I want to remove the Cancel button from a Save As Dialog Box! But by leafing through many subjects on the Internet, I still have no convincing results! Is it even possible?

I am developing an application, in vb.net.

```
Dim saveFileDialog1 As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Word Document (*.docx)|*.docx|Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)|*.doc|Plain Text (*.txt)|*.txt"
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
        saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = True
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files)

        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

            auxFile = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files) & ".docx"
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(files, auxFile)

        ElseIf DialogResult.Cancel Then

            saveFileDialog1.FileName = ""

        End If
```

Comment: You could simply display the dialogue in a loop until the user selects a file path, if selecting a file path is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog
    'Configure sfd here.

    Do Until sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK
    Loop

    'Use sfd.FileName here.
End Using
```

If you wanted to, you could display a message inside the loop to tell the user that they must select a file path. That will prevent them thinking that your app is broken if you haven't already made it clear that selecting a file path is mandatory.

Comment: Thank you very much jmcilhinney, I will implement the foruni code, thank you again :) Claude.